# scrape xml from a html page with getNodeSet

Tags: r, xpath, xml-parsing, html-parsing, web-scraping

Hi I am using R to do some basic web scraping where I am comfortable parsing xml file and querying them with xpath. However I am having difficulty parsing a full html page and trying to extract the xml to get into my comfort zone. For example:

```
parsedhtml <- htmlParse("http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp")
```

parses the html. I am using this because xmlParse only works on .xml files. I know that by using getNodeSet I can isolated specific nodes within the parsed html. So I am attempting to extract the embedded xml document under the "The Example XML Document" section by trying:

```
getNodeSet(parsedhtml, "//div[@class = 'code notranslate']")
```

where I get the data in the correct node, however it is not in standard xml and I am unable to parse this using xmlParse. My question is how do I use the result of getNodeSet to extract the xml?

Thanks very much

Comment: Your xpath is not correct don't give anything. But I think you are looking for `xmlValue`. apply it to your getNodeSet result.

Comment: As agstudy pointed out, you probably want to use `xmlValue`. To print the example doc, try e.g. `cat(xmlValue(nodeset[[1]]))`, where `nodeset` contains the output of `getNodeSet`.